# Why Windows 10 IoT is not supported on Raspberry Pi 2 B+ (v1.2)?

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I've been trying all the methods possibile to install it, with noobs (Windows 10 IoT wasn't even in the list),  Windows dashboard and manually (converting the .ffu to .img). I also  updated the firmware from raspbian but nothing changes, it stucks in the rainbow screen. I don't understand why, it has the same processor (BCM2837) as the pi 3 and it was released more than a year ago... 
So can you guys help me? At least to understand why it doesn't work. 
Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You could have a try to reference [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/Downloads) and download the latest Windows 10 Iot Core Dashboard. Then [setup your Raspberry Pi](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/Docs/GetStarted/rpi3/sdcard/stable/getstartedstep2) with Windows 10 Iot Core Dashboard.

Comment: I already tried as I said in the post, no result.

Comment: Is there any warning or error when Windows 10 Iot Core Dashboard is downloading or installing windows Iot core image?